# Load Image Bitmap in Simple Adapter and show in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I am working in a Android Activity , I have list view and loading data dynamicaly from server in json and for images i am getting bitmaps.

Where i am stuck is loading Bitmap Images in Listview how can i integrate image in simple adapter

Here is my code:

**single row xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusp"
    android:text="status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dspecs" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dspecs"
    android:text="speciality"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usr_dname" />





<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usr_dname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imug_p1"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imug_p1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hdoc"
    android:layout_above="@+id/statusp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**here i am adding a data**

```
 if(singleUser.has("picture")){

                    pic = singleUser.get("picture").toString();

                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(pic, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);


                 Drawable did = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte);



                }




     HashMap<String, String> docs = new HashMap<>();

                        docs.put("name", key);

                        docs.put("speciality",speci);

                        docs.put("status", status);

                        docs.put("picture",did.toString()); ///here i am adding bitmap

                        contactList.add(docs);
```

and here is simple adapter

```
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Users.this, contactList,R.layout.user_listitem,
                    new String[]{"picture","name","speciality" ,"status"},
                    new int[]{R.id.imug_p1,R.id.usr_dname,R.id.dspecs,R.id.statusp});
            usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
            ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But Nothing is shown in the listview .

**Edited**

i have converted bitmap to drawable even then i cannot saw any image  check my updated code.

Comment: Check this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: i have checked this , lazyadapter class doesnot resolve the errors

Comment: Please post the adapter code as text. You make it impossible now to quote from it.

Comment: see my edit adapter in code

Comment: Thanks. But you now have changed to `R.id.imug_p`. Which is ok. Before you had a drawable.

Comment: kindly check my edit

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your own adapter of a child of BaseAdapter. that is the only solution

Comment: can i have tried using custom adapter . but then my data is also not shown , i think i did not match the correct reference . by looking my above code can u give any modified example of code how should i use custom adapter

Comment: do u know recyclerview?

Comment: yes Its better than to use recuclerview than listview , but i am new i dont know how to code it

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ check it once